# Optimized way to fetch distinct records from table after each query execution

Tags: mysql

Scenario,
Suppose in my table 100 records, and in one query execution i fetch 10 records so if execute the query 10 times.then records should be distinct in all query execution.

Comment: No, as per mysql concern there is no such facility to do this. One can be that keep record of fetched rows in a another table and on next execution fetch records other than records added in that table using `NOT IN`

Comment: it would only be that way if you specified something in the WHERE clause which made sure it selected rows it hadn't selected before - for that you would need a separate record of which rows had been selected before, of course. Without more specifics about your scenario it's not really possible to give any more advice.